# How to put vertical buttons next to my router-outlet in Angular2

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I want to have a sidebar of vertical buttons to the left of my router outlet but it displays below the buttons? This is in my app.component.ts file:

```
template: `
  <sidebar></sidebar>
    <div class= "container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
```

The sidebar component is:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1st Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2nd Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3rd Button</button>
</div>
```

What is the best way to have a list of buttons next to the content that's being routed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use bootstrap layout to get what you want:

```
<div class=" col col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
    <sidebar></sidebar>
</div>
<div class=" col col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nicholas glad to hear :) close this question by accepting answer if it solved your issue